# Get Column names with Delphi (Dbexpress)

Tags: sql, delphi, dbexpress

I'm using this sql command to get column names :

```
select COLUMN_NAME from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'
```

but i don't know how can i using the executed SQL command results !

for example , this way doesn't work to extract the column names as a string value and i got this error = Operation Not Supported :

```
  for i := 1 to Qry1.RecordCount do
  begin

  end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work for a TADOQuery (not sure if it's different for dbExpress):

```
Qry1.Open;
while not Qry1.Eof do begin
    // do whatever with Qry1.Fields[0].AsString here
    Qry1.Next;
end;
Qry1.Close;
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way you can do this is to query the table itself to get an empty dataset, and then loop through the fields in that dataset.

A query like this will return the table structure with no records in it:

```
Qry1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE 1<>1';
Qry1.Open;
```

And a loop like this will iterate through each field

```
for I := 0 to Qry1.FieldCount-1 do
begin
  X := Qry1.Fields[I].FieldName;
  // and do whatever you want with X
end;
```

Comment: X would always have the first row's value.

no .Next call there

Comment: No, X will have the column name. That's what the original question asked for.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are unable to retreive the retults.

```
Qry1.First;

while not Qry1.Eof do
begin
    X := Qry1.FieldByName('column_name').AsString;

    Qry1.Next;
end;
```

This is a piece of code which has always worked for me

Or you can read this link which explains why the exception is thrown when calling .RecordCount (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28494)

To sum it up it suggests that your query is case-sensitive and you should probably check the table name (MyTableName)

Answer (score 1):

agree with Rob McDonell, in order to list the column name of a field, I'll use that
as in my code I wrote something like this

```
Procedure blablabla;
var i:integer;
begin
..... {some code here}

SQLQuery1.Open;
  for i := 0 to SQLQuery1.FieldCount-1 do
    begin;
    Memo1.Lines.Append(SQLQuery1.Fields[i].DisplayName);
    end;
  SQLQuery1.Close;


.... {some code here}

end;
```